# How to include break in a Dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query that helps me select the column names which have null values. what I want to do is update only the first column's value. I tried to include a break statement after the update query to exit the cursor's while loop but I get this error 
Cannot use a `BREAK` statement outside the scope of a 
`WHILE` statement.
this is the code I tried

```
AS
declare @col varchar(255), @cmd varchar(max)

DECLARE getinfo cursor for
SELECT c.name FROM sys.tables t JOIN sys.columns c ON t.Object_ID = c.Object_ID
WHERE t.Name = 'Grilles_de_tailles' and c.name like 'T%'

OPEN getinfo

FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @cmd = 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Grilles_de_tailles WHERE [' + @col + '] IS NOT NULL and Code_Grille_BW = '+@codegrillebw+') begin 
update Grilles_de_tailles set ['+@col+'] = '+@libtaille+' where Code_Grille_BW = '+@codegrillebw+'
break
end'
    EXEC(@cmd)
    FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col
END

CLOSE getinfo
DEALLOCATE getinfo
```

I also tried this way

```
AS
declare @col varchar(255), @cmd varchar(max), @breakval numeric
SET @breakval=0

DECLARE getinfo cursor for
SELECT c.name FROM sys.tables t JOIN sys.columns c ON t.Object_ID = c.Object_ID
WHERE t.Name = 'Grilles_de_tailles' and c.name like 'T%'

OPEN getinfo

FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 AND @breakval=0
BEGIN
    SELECT @cmd = 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Grilles_de_tailles WHERE [' + @col + '] IS NOT NULL and Code_Grille_BW = '+@codegrillebw+') begin 
update Grilles_de_tailles set ['+@col+'] = '+@libtaille+' where Code_Grille_BW = '+@codegrillebw+'
set '+@breakval+' = '+1+'

end'
    EXEC(@cmd)
    FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col
END

CLOSE getinfo
DEALLOCATE getinfo
```

this way it doesn't even enter the while loop

I tried to use GOTO , this is the code

````
DECLARE getinfo cursor 
for 
SELECT c.name FROM sys.tables t JOIN sys.columns c ON t.Object_ID = c.Object_ID 

WHERE t.Name = 'Grilles_de_tailles' and c.name like 'T%'


OPEN getinfo
FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col 


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN
 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Grilles_de_tailles WHERE  @col  IS NOT NULL 
and Code_Grille_BW = '2456')
BEGIN 
print ('aaaa')
update Grilles_de_tailles set @col = 'M'
GOTO Branch_one


END


    FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col

END

Branch_one:
CLOSE getinfo
DEALLOCATE getinfo ``` 

nothing happened I got "Commands completed successfully" but it seems that it didn't execute the instructions between BEGIN .. END since the print didn't work
````

Comment: 1) Do not use `VARCHAR(n)` instead use `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. 2) Your code is wide open to SQL Injection. 3) Use **[`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** instead of `EXEC`. 4) Since there is no `ORDER BY` clause then there is no First/Last rows, you need to specify in which order.

Comment: It sounds like a very odd requirement to only want to update the first column. You also don't provide an `order by`, so you're not guaranteed which column you'll update.

Comment: You could simply use `@@ROWCOUNT` to check if the statement updated anything. For more advanced scenarios, you can use `sp_executesql` with an `OUTPUT` variable. That said, looping over dynamic statements tends to be inferior to investing some more effort into producing one dynamic statement (through string concatenation) that does everything in a set-based manner. (Plus, what the others said -- use `ORDER BY` and `QUOTENAME` judiciously.)

Comment: in tsql you use goto and then have an anchor in the bottom

Comment: @HoneyBadger my requirement is based on that each column should have a different value of the variable @ libtaille that I'm getting from an other application from each iteration of a loop as an input variable to the precedure described above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
declare @col varchar(255), @cmd varchar(max)

DECLARE getinfo cursor for
SELECT c.name FROM sys.tables t JOIN sys.columns c ON t.Object_ID = c.Object_ID
WHERE t.Name = 'Grilles_de_tailles' and c.name like 'T%'

OPEN getinfo

FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    declare @Break bit=0
    SELECT @cmd = 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Grilles_de_tailles WHERE [' + @col + '] IS NOT NULL and Code_Grille_BW = '+@codegrillebw+') begin 
update Grilles_de_tailles set ['+@col+'] = '+@libtaille+' where Code_Grille_BW = '+@codegrillebw+'
SET @Break=1
end'
    exec sp_executesql @cmd,'@Break bit OUTPUT',@Break OUTPUT
    IF @Break=1
        break

    FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col
END

CLOSE getinfo
DEALLOCATE getinfo
```